# Strange div margin issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a content rotator to a site I'm building. The rotator works fine. In fact, it works out better than I had hoped. I need to tweak some styling things, but that's besides the point.

For some reason, the rotator (which is relatively positioned and inside my container/wrapper div) pulls my wrapper and menu down with it when I add a margin to the top of it (`margin:65px auto 0;` or something like that). Any words of advice?

Page here:
http://technoheads.org/test/ice/index.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a classic case of [collapsing margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102640/css-margin-collapsing).

You can fix this by giving the container a `border-top`, `margin-top`, `padding-top`, or an `overflow` other than `visible`.  ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qw6R5/))

Comment: Not quite: the two are nested. Try inspecting the page and adding a top margin to the slideshow. In both Firefox 3.6.6 and Chrome (whichever latest build) I've had the issue (I'm not on my computer, hence the outdated firefox).

Comment: Nested elements are affected by margin collapse, check out the jsFiddle I link.  I was able to get your page to work as intended by adding `overflow:auto` to `#wrapper` and setting the margins you mention on `#slidesContainer` via FireBug.

Comment: +1 for collapsing margins - similarly I added 1px padding to top of #wrapper and achieved the same as @Ben's screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you can probably accomplish what you want by giving #wrapper top padding instead giving #slideshow top margin.

Comment: I thought of that, but I don't want a band-aid. I kinda want to know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem a lot when I put elements inside of inline elements. You should be able to fix it by doing one of the following:

- Set the element you're having trouble with to `display: block;` (Usually a good enough fix)
- Use top-padding like already suggested (nothing wrong with using band-aids if it works...)
- Set the element to `float: left;` (Not really recommended, can cause some problems down the line, but will definitely allow you to add top and bottom margins)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#menu {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  left: 383px;
  top: 0px;
}
```