# CSS margin-top influencing outer <div>

Tags: css, html, layout

```
 <body>
  <div id="naslov">
    <img src="image/Conto_logo.png" title="Conto Regis" alt="contologo" />
  </div>
  <div id="izbornik">
    <div id="home">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

 body {
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size:1.0em;
    font-weight:100;
    margin:0px;
    color:#000;
}
div#naslov {
    height: 128px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../image/Header.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
div#naslov > img {
    cursor:pointer;
    height: 80px;
    margin:20px 0px 0px 20px;
}
div#izbornik {
    width:100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-image: url(../image/izbornik.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#home{
    height:27px;
    width:28px;
    border:#000 1px dashed;
}
```

I'm having problem positioning div "home" inside div "izbornik" when I use margin-top to pull div "home" a bit down something strange happens. Dreamweaver displays it fine while IE10 and Chrome(latest) display it as if I used margin-top inside div "izbornik". Funny thing is if set div "home" to float:left margin starts acting normal but I'm not sure why, I'll be using some javascript later when the template is completed and I need the page to be very very stable. Any suggestions?
http://jsfiddle.net/xNrGR/6/ => in short why does that 8px gap appear there? I need the div "home" to go down not the whole parent-child combo

Comment: [Be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102640/css-margin-collapsing) [aware of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) [`margin collapse`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins‎)

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is: http://jsfiddle.net/xNrGR/

Comment: put some colors instead of urls and put "margin-top:8px" in #home{} you'll see that the parent div moves down while the child div stays nested inside it.. and I'm trying to get that child div to move down inside the parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to `#izbornik`. Seems to be a collapsing margins issue.

```
div#izbornik {
    width:100%;
    height: 45px;
    background: red;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xNrGR/8/)**

Comment: A little long to explain, but read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing or Google collpasing margins.

Answer (score 0):

This is [collapsing margins](http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/). You can fix this by setting `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden` to the parent div. This can cause issue for some users depending on the content you have.

The other option is to give the parent div a border. If you make the border the sam color as the background it would not be noticeable. When people use 1px border they normally use margin -1px too. These are just some ways of tackling the problem.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/xNrGR/9/

`border: thin solid red;`