# a strange position issue when adding border for a div

Tags: html, css, border, css-position, margin

html:

```
    <div class="outside">
         <div class="inside">
         </div>
    </div>
```

I have two CSS : #1 and #2

```
 /*CSS#1 does not work*/
.outside{
    background: blue;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.inside{
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -100px; /*half height of this div*/
}

/*CSS#2 works well */
.outside{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.inside{
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -100px; /*half height of this div*/
}
```

My aim is to place the 'inside' div at the center of the 'outside' div (both vertical and horizontal). I have a lot of ways to achieve this aim, however I found something strange during the process.

I found that CSS#2 works quite well, but CSS#1 does not work: when setting the 'inside' div 'margin-top: -100px', the 'outside' also moves up..

Here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dQaRu/)**

So I am wondering why 'border' works well here and why 'background' does not work?

Comment: At end, the problem is solved successfully by Mr.Allen's kind help.
And I found a very nice paragraph which is about callapsing margin: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [`overflow: auto;`](http://jsfiddle.net/dQaRu/1/) to the parent element there, but however your approach is incorrect, you need to `position` your child element `absolute` to the parent element and not `relative`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ssy2E/)

---

Using `overflow: auto;` or `border` will fix your issue as it prevents [collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) of the parent `margin`.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much for your help! I know the 'absolute' way, but do not know why 'overflow: auto' works here.. may you explain it for me ... thank you! I also feel confused why 'border: 1px solid black' works well even without 'overflow: auto'....

Comment: @DingArne http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102640/css-margin-collapsing It prevents collapsing margin

Comment: Thank you, Mr.Alien. I think I got my answer through your help! I will dig into the resources you provided, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to set top and left as 25 %. I have tested it on ie 11 and crome.It is working fine.

```
.outside{
    background: blue;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.inside{
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    left:25%;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Priyank. This only works for my issue when the 'inside' div has half width&height of the 'outside' div... I am really curious about why 'border: 1px solid black' works well here rather than using 'background: blue' directly.