# When I add a border to a div in HTML, the padding get's altered. How do I fix this? [simple example code]

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="header">
        <h2>Hi</h2>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS file:

```
#header {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;

}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

When I add the "border: 2px solid black;" line in the CSS, the #header div suddenly becomes really tall. How do I make it not do this? I've tried altering padding and height but it doesn't work.

Why does adding a border do this, and how do I change this? Thanks! First post on stackexchange so apologies if this is formatted incorrectly :)

Comment: Why are you using relative positioning at all?

Comment: Seems like it is just fine http://jsfiddle.net/xE7HT/

Comment: adding a border of 2px will increase the total height of your element by 4px

Comment: What do you mean with really tall?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Margin Collapsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102640/css-margin-collapsing)

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin to 0 on the h2 element.

```
h2 { 
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/r2ykc/