# Parent div is moved to bottom because I specified a child div margin

Tags: html, css

I've written the following markup and styles:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>

#parent{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:aqua;

}
#child{
    margin: 100px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:black;

}
```

So why doesn't the `div#parent` appear at the left-top corner, but is moved to the bottom?
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWF8k/)
But if we consider the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWF8k/3) then it works as I'm expected.

Comment: Why is the margin on #child? If you remove it, it should sit on in the top left of the parent by default.

Comment: Well, it's difficult to answer without research, but I know for sure that it is expected behavior across all browsers defined by the true specifications.

Comment: You can read enough here, but I don't think it's useful for anything except basic understanding of stylesheets http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: That's a [margin](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins) [collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102640/css-margin-collapsing).

Answer (score 0):

`margin` of `#child` makes `#parent` to move.

In first [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nWF8k/10/) margin,height,width are 100px,500px,500px and in second [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nWF8k/9/), margin,height,width are 10px,10px,200px respectively.

Changing margin,height and width would obviously give different output but if you OBSERVE carefully, margin still remains and it does not resolve your issue.

`#parent` is not at the top-left corner in both cases. You can see yellow color in both fiddles.

Write:

```
#parent{
    position:relative;
}
#child{
    position:absolute;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nWF8k/8/)

Comment: I'm repeat my question: **Why** div#parent doesn't appear at the top-left corner. But if we consider the following http://jsfiddle.net/nWF8k/3/ then it works as I'm expected.

Comment: @Dmitrii I have updated my answer. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: `Why div#parent doesn't appear at the top-left corner. But if we consider the following jsfiddle.net/nWF8k/3 then it works as I'm expected.` Your question was answered by @Hashem above. It's a "margin collapse" issue. The second fiddle displays the *same* behavior, but just not as noticably because the child div has a much smaller top margin.