# can't get text to align in two css horizontal boxes

Tags: html, css

I'm (hopefully) trying to horizontally align the text in two div boxes , but as you can see below it isn't happening for me . Please help as I can't see what I'm doing wrong

```
        <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.left-div {
    vertical-align:top;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
        }
.right-div {
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-left: 400px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="left-div">
<H2> Telephone:</H2>
<strong>Mobile: </strong>     123456789<br />
<strong>Office: </strong>     123456789(answer service)<br />
<strong> Email: </strong><a href="mailto:bg@hotmail.co.uk" style="text-decoration:none;">pgbathrooms@hotmail.co.uk</a>
</div>

<div class="right-div">
<H2>Address:</H2>
house<br />
town<br />
county<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [As in center the text?](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/Z42XU/)

Comment: Align how? Center vertically?

Comment: sorry, have the text horizontally aligned across both boxes.

Comment: Judging from the answers it looks like you mean vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eTME/)

The problem you were having was actually the [margin-collapse problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/102755/870729), which was manifesting because your `h2` has margin-top, and it was being reflected in one div and not the other.

Vertical-align does not work on block-level elements, only inline-block or inline elements.

You could do one of two things:

1. Remove the margin-top from your h2: `div h2 {margin-top: 0;}`
2. You could add padding to the top of the divs to give the margin something to "push off of"

Changing your css as follows takes care of the problem:

```
.left-div {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.right-div {
    margin-left: 400px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
```