# Margin affecting parent > sibling items?

Tags: html, css

Why does `.ibg .im` margin setting effect the text alignment?

I've tried finding a solution to this but the vagueness of the search terms aren't bringing up results in Google.

Can anyone shed light on this? Any assistance appreciated.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/775zA/1/

To see my issue, remove the margin from the `.ibg .im` CSS rule.

[image]

CSS

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.ibg {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ibg .im {
    margin: 8px;
}
.olist {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    list-style: none;

}
.olist li {
    list-style: none;
}
.olist .lbl {
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="starter-template">
        <ul class='olist'>
          <li>
            <div class='ibg' style='background-color: #B1BF54'>
              <div class='im'>
                <img src='http://placehold.it/32x32/000000/ffffff&text=img' />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='lbl'>Title here</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>      
    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

**UPDATE**

So it seems that this question touches on this subject: [CSS Margin Collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102640/css-margin-collapsing). However it does not address a way to remove the sibling padding/margin.

Say I wanted to to have text occur in line with the top of the green box... is there no way to do this without `position:relative;` and `top:-8px`? That solution seems unnecessarily hackish response to a very strange CSS quirk

Comment: Setting `vertical-align: top` to `.lbl` may be what you need, see demo in my posted answer.

Comment: Also related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
        <ul class='olist'>
            <li>x
                <div class='ibg' style='background-color: #B1BF54'>
                    <div class='im'>
                        <img src='http://placehold.it/32x32/000000/ffffff&text=img' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='lbl'>Title here</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

I added the letter `x` at the start of the `li` element to illustrate where the default base line is located, which in this case, is the bottom of the character `x`.

After the `x`, you have the inline-block `.ibg` which contains an image nested in a block level element `.im` (but this block simply lies within the parent inline-block, so it does not affect the baseline in this case).  By default, the bottom of the image will be aligned on the baseline determined by the parent element, in this case, the `li` element.

You then have the `.lbl` element, which is also inline-block, so the bottom of that text box is also aligned with the baseline determined by the `li`.

If you were to change the `line-height` of the `li` or `vertical-align`, you would see the effect.

In fact, you can change the `vertical-align` value on each of the inline elements to get a staggered effect, as shown in the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9R4zn/

[image: sample]

**Key Point:**
The parent element sets the base line level for the enclosed inline elements (even deeply nested inline blocks).

Comment: Great answer, very well written. Thanks for your help Marc!

Answer (score 1):

make both `.ibg` and `.lbl` `vertical-align:middle`

http://jsfiddle.net/775zA/2/

Comment: That may solve my issue but doesn't answer my question as to *why*

Comment: because browser default is ```vertical-align:baseline```

Comment: I mean, it doesn't explain why the CSS of a deeply nested item is affecting the parents and siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.ibg, .olist .lbl{
 vertical-align:middle
}
```

Comment: That may solve my issue but doesn't answer my question as to *why*