# p tag inside div and margin collapse, can't understand

Tags: css, css-position

**HTML:**

```
<div>  
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    margin-top: 20px;
}  

div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Margin means space around a box **FROM ITS PARENT**. right?
why my p tag doen't get top margin from div? instead from body. I mean p and div get attached together.
I know with floating we can solve this. or applying border or padding.
My question is: Is there any collapsing? what's happening?

**EDIT:**
Sorry guys.
I know the solution as I said. I want to know the underlying concept.

Margin applies to OUTSIDE of an element.

But Consider p tag. it is INSIDE. whatever margin we give to p tag, should only apply to its siblings. not outer elements like its parent or div.

Comment: Also, another similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102640/css-margin-collapsing

Comment: I read them. I'm still not getting the point. tanx for closing

Comment: I don't think you read this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins from the very first answer on the question in my comment

Answer (score 1):

This is called [**Margin Collapsing**](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/).

One solution is adding a `padding` to your `parent` element:

```
p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: yellow;
}  

div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
```

---

Another solution is adding `overflow` to your parent element:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

See this [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xyjj3qzs/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use padding:

```
p { padding-top: 20px; }
div { width: 400px; height: 80px; background-color:blue}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t1acatL1/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you didn't set any postion to **div** element.

Set **position:absolute** to div element.

```
div{
   position: absolute;
   width: 400px;
   height: 80px;
}
```

That's it. Now check it.

Comment: `position: absolute` will affect the next elements.

Comment: Then, You need to set position:relative to other elements.