# CSS Margin-top also effects parent

Tags: html, css

I want to run a button in my menu, but every time that I set the `margin-top` propperty to 10, the parent also goes 10 pixels down...

here's my code:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0.1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

#menuknop {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url(../img/menuknopje.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 101;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-left:95%
}
```

And my HTML, really simple":

```
    <nav>
    <div id='menuknop'></div>
</nav>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: i got the same problem so i just gave nav{ padding-top:10px;} instead of margin in menu

Comment: @himanshu If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). There are at least three ways to prevent margin collapsing:

- Adding `overflow: hidden`
- Adding border
- Adding padding

Setting any of these will prevent the margin of an element to collapse with that of its first child.

**Solution 1:** you already have a 0.1px border, if you could change it to 1px the problem will disappear (seems like 0.1px borders are ignored anyway):

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
#menuknop {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: orange;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 101;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 95%
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id='menuknop'></div>
</nav>
```

**Solution 2:** add a (pseudo) element with hidden overflow:

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
nav:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menuknop {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: orange;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 101;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 95%
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id='menuknop'></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

use padding in nav instead of margin in #menuknop

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0.1px solid #fff;
    padding-top:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px -3px 7px -1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

#menuknop {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url(../img/menuknopje.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 101;
    position: relative;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-left:95%
}
```

but i dont know the correct reason of this behavior if someone know please let me know

Comment: The reason is about `margin collapse`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102640/css-margin-collapsing

Answer (score 1):

It's [margin collapsing](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/) - documented and intended CSS behavior for laying out flows of text, for which it was originally designed.

To prevent this behavior when it is not needed, there are several options:

1. Add some top padding or top border to a parent element. It doesn't have to be visible, it just should be non-zero. `border-top: transparent solid .01px` should be sufficient in most cases.
2. Make the parent element establish new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context). Usually it is done by setting `overflow:hidden` to it, but this has some limitations.
3. Add an empty (pseudo) element that establishes block formatting context before the child element. So does the popular [micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).
4. Take the child element from the blocks flow, e.g. by making it `float`ing or by changing its `display` to `inline-block` (as suggested in comments to the question).

Choose what fits your requirements:)

Answer (score 0):

Use translate

```
#menuknop {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url(../img/menuknopje.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 101;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(10px,0,0);
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-left:95%
}
```